# How to install pygments on windows 7

Tags: minted, pygments

When I run LaTeX file its gives error as  "*! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize` installed to use this package*", you must have `pygments` installed. when I go through minted documentation minted itself required pygments, so Tex friend How do I install this pygment, I don't know the procedure to install. Please guid me or any link pygement.exe file

Comment: Install Python and then use it. It's all described on its [website](http://pygments.org/).

Comment: I already have python versions of 3.4@TeXnician

Comment: in linux there is no problem in running the same latex file but in windows there gives me the error@TeXnician

Comment: Get rid of windows.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

As stated on its website, pygments is a tool written in Python. So you have to do the following:

1. Download and install a Python 3.X version from https://www.python.org/downloads/. Make sure it's in your path.
2. Open a shell in administrator mode and issue `pip install Pygments`.
3. Compile your LaTeX document.

Comment: Thanking you, after "pip install Pygments" i need to set the environtment variable as "C:\Python27\Scripts" then it is working normally. @TeXnician

Comment: @Biki: how to to set the environtment variable as "C:\Python27\Scripts"? (I am using Windows 10 )

Comment: @BikiTeron I know it is very old post. But now I get same problem. I installed pycharm community edition 2017,using windows 10. Also get a folder name Pygments in C:\Users\Ellena\Anaconda2\Lib\site-packages path. Still got error in TexStudio. Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package. \begin{document}. How could you solve your problem? What is pip install Pygments?

Comment: @Encipher Pip is a python package manager which may be used to install Pygments. Your folder name indicates that your installation of pygmentize is not in your path. Please use one of the many guides available online to add that path to PATH.

Comment: Why does Latex need python? I expected it to be self-sufficient

Comment: @skan It's not LaTeX that requires Python but Pygments (a fairly non-trivial Python application which does quite a good job at syntax highlighting). That's why this post refers to Pygments (see question). The `minted` package uses Pygments, so Python is required for all documents using `minted`. And no, `minted` is not that special here, there are quite a numer of "hard" tasks (e.g. locale-aware sorting or graphics conversion) which are left to external programs in other languages.

Comment: @TeXnician I meant why don't those packages use just LaTeX or LuaTeX?

Comment: @skan LuaTeX is quite powerful but by far not the usual default engine, so for a broad user base you need something different. And doing it all in TeX would be enormous effort for a much slower compilation. Furthermore, relying on some of these external programs that are very common saves a few TeX enthusiasts to (re)write a complete, domain-specific syntax highlighting tool, because Pygments is well-maintained and developed. Hence, there has not been any real incentive to drop Pygments in favor of something own. Even in ConTeXt one does not use Lua callbacks but vim for syntax highlighting.