# How to install pygments package on Windows 10?

Tags: packages

I have a problem with this error message:

"Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package."

I read [this post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369600/how-to-install-pygments-on-windows-7) but I don't overcome the problem.

I installed Python 3.6 (32-bit). Can anybody help me?

Comment: Did you run `pip install pygments` on command line to install the `pygments` package itself after having installed Python?

Comment: No. I don't know how can I do it. I tried to launch the pip.exe and pip36.exe in the folder C:\Program Files\Python36-32\Scripts but it's close itself (can't run). Could you please tell me more detailed how can I run it? Btw, thanks. @epR8GaYuh

Comment: If you run this command, try running `pygmentize -V`. It should show a version number.

Comment: If you haven't run pip: You need to open a command prompt (CMD, maybe as admin) and then paste it in there. I must admit: My answer uses the term "shell" which must be very confusing for a Windows user... But it is written there that you need that step.

Comment: Thank you I did it! But now it gives me this error: "Undefined control sequence. \PYG{n}{clear} \PYG{n}{all}" @TeXnician

Comment: That's not related to the installation. But probably related to how you include the minted package. You should open a new question with a minimal code example asking for minted-specific help.

Comment: I deleted temporary folder named like "minted_mytexfilename" in my tex folder and it's ok! Thank you again! @TeXnician

Comment: The path for microsoft app store python scripts is C:\Users\USERNAME\AppData\Local\Packages\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_qbz5n2kfra8p0\LocalCache\local-packages\Python39\Scripts ; That had to be added to system paths and texstudio had to be restarded. I also had to delete a temporary folder like lynx mentioned.