# Trouble using pygmentize as standard user in Windows

Tags: listings, miktex, texmaker, pygments

i have some problems with `pygmentize`. I know that there are already a few questions in this forum concerning `pygmentize` but i can't find a solution for my problem.

I'm using Texmaker with Miktex as "standard user" in Windows 10. (**no** Admin!)

My program looks like this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{float}

\usepackage{bm}

\usepackage{color}

\usepackage[minted, most]{tcolorbox}
\definecolor{bg}{rgb}{0.85,0.85,0.85}

\usepackage{sidecap}
\renewcommand\sidecaptionsep{2cm}

\usepackage{listings}

\usepackage[a4paper,margin=2cm,bottom=2cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}

\newtcblisting[blend into = listings]{code}[1][]{
listing engine = minted ,
minted language = python ,
colback = bg ,
minted options = { linenos } ,
listing only ,
left = 6mm ,
lefttitle = 0mm ,
leftrule = 0pt ,
rightrule = 0pt ,
bottomrule = 0pt ,
coltitle = black ,
colframe = gray!70 ,
fonttitle = \small,
arc = 0pt ,
#1
}

\begin{code}[title=Parameter der \mintinline{python}{compare}-Methode, label=code:Parameter compare method listing]
compare(self, crack_comp, method, output_file=None)
\end{code}

\end{document}
```

But when i'm running my program (**with** `-shell-escape`), i get an error `You must have pygmentize installed...`.
After some research in the Internet i have added a `PATH` variable with the path to my `pygmentize-file`. (i'm using `anaconda3` so my `pygmentize-file` has a path like `C:/Users/Dominik/ananconda3/Scripts`. Then i change my Windows-User to a `Administrator`. After that my program works.

But is it possible to run this program as `standard user`? So is there another possibilty than adding a `PATH` variable?

Comment: this may help -- https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/521010/pygmentize-error-while-compiling-with-minted-package

Comment: I have a problem because i'm using Texmaker and can't find `ST3>Preferences>Package Settings>LatexTools>Settings-User>Platform Settings` as described in your linked answer. I don't know how to find the `LaTeXTools  configuration file` as well.