# I can't get minted package to work under MikTeX in Windows

Tags: miktex, minted, windows

I'm trying to compile a document which needs the package `minted`, but it throws the same error over and over:

```
! Package minted Error: You must have `pygmentize' installed to use this package
```

I can't seem to make it work. Other forums say to install the package "Pygments," which is a Python package, but MikTeX doesn't seem to have that package in its repositories. Am I missing something? Do I have to install another LaTeX motor or something?

Edit:

Before anybody asks, yes I'm using the "-shell-escape" flag to compile the document which minted requieres.

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE. You should install `Pygments` into your computer for `minted`

Comment: If you are Windows user, this https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/369600/how-to-install-pygments-on-windows-7 will helps you

Answer (score 0):

All right, so as it turns out, minted is a package that requieres Python installed with the package "Pygments" included. I happen to use Anaconda for python, so I had to modify the "Path" variable to include the installation directory of Anaconda, and using the Anaconda Navigator, I used the command:

```
conda install -c anaconda pygments
```

And then also

```
pip install Pygments
```

which for some reason seemed to work. However after that, I also had to include the directory of the "Pygments" package in the "Path" variable (C:/.../Anaconda/Scripts) and set is as high priority (above the rest of the Paths that execute LaTeX), and then restart the computer. Done that, the package minted finally worked.